# pandas-percentage count of categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas df like

`df_test = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'a a a b b'.split(), 'B': ['Y','N','Y','Y','N']})`

and my desired output to be 
`df_test2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'a b'.split(), 'B': [2/3,1/2]})`
How would you do a groupby().apply by column A to get the percentage of 'Y' in column B?

I have been searching groupby.apply() but nothing have worked so far
Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach could be

```
In [10]: df_test.groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x: (x == 'Y').mean())
Out[10]:
A
a    0.666667
b    0.500000
```

or, if you don't mind changing `df_test` in the process,

```
In [15]: df_test['C'] = df_test.B == 'Y'
In [17]: df_test.groupby('A').C.mean()
Out[17]:
A
a    0.666667
b    0.500000
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 14):

personal favorite way:

```
df.column_name.value_counts() / len(df)
```

Gives a series with the column's values as the index and the proportions as the values.

Answer (score 8):

This is a generalized solution which doesn't alter the table or does any kind of filtering or transformation before using groupby.

```
> s = df_test.groupby(['A'])['B'].value_counts(normalize=True)
> print(s)

A  B
a  Y    0.666667
   N    0.333333
b  N    0.500000
   Y    0.500000
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Above variable **s** is a multi-index series and you can access any rows using
**.loc**

```
> s.loc[:,'Y']
A
a    0.666667
b    0.500000
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Similarly, you can access the details about 'N' using the same series.

```
> s.loc[:,'N']
A
a    0.333333
b    0.500000
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

**PS:**
If you want to understand **groupby** better then try to decode this code which is exactly similar of above but only alters the column names and results differnetly.

```
> r = df_test.groupby(['B'])['A'].value_counts(normalize=True)
> print(r)
B  A
N  a    0.500000
   b    0.500000
Y  a    0.666667
   b    0.333333
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

and

```
> r.loc['Y',:]
B  A
Y  a    0.666667
   b    0.333333
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) with boolean mask, where `True`s are processes like `1`, no new column is necessary, because also is pass `Series` `df_test["A"]` to `groupby`:

*Notice:*

*Instead  `==` is used [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) for cleaner syntax.*

```
df = df_test["B"].eq('Y').groupby(df_test["A"]).mean().reset_index()
print (df)
   A         B
0  a  0.666667
1  b  0.500000
```